# Assign constant value to a variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a constant declared in my TypeScript file and later at some point
I need to get them in a variable, but I can't figure out how it's done.

Here's my code:

```
const Color: {} = {
  RED: {
    CODE: "RCB",
    PRICE: 15.70
  },
  BLUE: {
    CODE: "BBC",
    PRICE: 18.70
  },
  GREEN: {
    CODE: "GTA",
    PRICE: 13.70
  },
};
let price: Color = Color.RED.PRICE;
console.log(price);
```

`let price: Color = Color.RED.PRICE;` is not working, I am getting the following error messages:

```
Cannot find name Color
```

and:

```
Property RED does not exist on type '{}'
```

Comment: The first error is because `Color` isn't a type, it's an identifier. The second is because you've explicitly typed it as `{}`, which indeed doesn't have a `RED` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use an explicit type annotation telling the typescript compiler that `Color` is an empty object (`: {}`). You just need to remove that and the compiler will infer the correct type of the variable.

```
const Color = {
  RED: {
    CODE: "RCB",
    PRICE: 15.70
  },
  BLUE: {
    CODE: "BBC",
    PRICE: 18.70
  },
  GREEN: {
    CODE: "GTA",
    PRICE: 13.70
  },
};
let price  = Color.RED.PRICE;
console.log(price);
```

Also `price` is a number and again you can just let the compiler infer that.

If you want to declare a variable that is one of the properties in the `Color` object you can use a type query :

```
let red: typeof Color[keyof typeof Color]  = Color.RED;
```

`typeof Color` gets the inferred type of the constant, and `[keyof typeof Color]` tells the compiler we want a union of all property types of `Color`.

We can also put this type in an alias for later use:

```
type ColorMember = typeof Color[keyof typeof Color];
let red: ColorMember  = Color.RED;
```

Comment: sorry if my question seems silly...This explanation was exactly what i was looking for...Thankz a lot....

Comment: @ScrappyCocco not silly, just a beginner question, that's why I included more info :)

Answer (score 1):

do it like this :

```
const Color = {
   RED: {
     CODE: "RCB",
     PRICE: 15.70
   },
   BLUE: {
     CODE: "BBC",
     PRICE: 18.70
   },
   GREEN: {
     CODE: "GTA",
     PRICE: 13.70
   },
 };
var price = Color.RED.PRICE; 

console.log(price); //15.70
```